# Angular 2 RC4 TestComponentBuilder - fixture.detectChanges() - gives no value accessor error

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to write a unit test using the TestComponentBuilder for an angular 2 app.  When I call fixture.detectChanges() I get a no value accessor for 'settingName' error.  Anybody have an idea why this would happen?

**Here is a repo to see the error.  It uses angular-cli**
https://github.com/bluefalcon/angular2-model-form-spec

**here is the error:**
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for 'settingName'
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: No value accessor for 'settingName'
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/forms/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
    at _throwError (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/shared.js:55:11)
    at Object.setUpControl (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/shared.js:30:9)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.js:71:18)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.js:39:32)
    at DebugAppView._View_SettingComponent0.detectChangesInternal (SettingComponent.template.js:198:55)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:243:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:348:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:269:19)
    at DebugAppView._View_SettingComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (SettingComponent.template.js:37:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:243:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:348:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:131:65)
    at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/testing/component_fixture.js:63:32)
    at eval (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/testing/component_fixture.js:77:49)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:323:29)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/async-test.js?8f51e44ce2093ec5167bc06760f15344db17d094:76:44)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:322:35)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:53:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:322:35)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:216:44)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInner (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:84:71)
    at NgZone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:235:66)
    at ComponentFixture.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/@angular/core/testing/component_fixture.js:77:25)
    at eval (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/app/setting/setting.component.spec.js:31:29)
    at F (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:7484)
    at H (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:7116)
    at q.when (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:10790)
    at b.run (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:9826)
    at t._drain (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:1744)
    at drain (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:1398)
    at MutationObserver.e (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?a9f0c97e865a53da4c067b98cf2e65a23b2f0608:4:3319)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:323:29)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:230:48)
    at MutationObserver. (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js?8b9c8d0a7e549abe9edec8da5a095f206d206277:206:30)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]"

Comment: beforeEach was removed from `@angular/core/testing` and it should be used as part of the  built in Jasmine functions as mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9564. However I am not sure that this is what causes the issue.

Comment: thanks @knikolov for pointing that out.  I went ahead and fixed that.  Yes you are correct, that did not resolve the issue, but prevented an issue down the road.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  I love it when the answer is simple. Needed to add disableDeprecatedForms() and provideForms() to the addProviders([]).  Oh yeah don't forget the '()'